# Primefaces menubar actionListener

Tags: primefaces, menu

Hi i have an p:manubar

```
 <p:menubar model="#{topMenu.model}"/>
```

And i would like to call action listener on action event and store the active tab.
How could I do that?
This is my model bean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "topMenu")
@RequestScoped

public class TopMenuBean {

public MenuModel model;
private UIViewRoot viewRoot;
private final MenuHelper menuHelper = new MenuHelper();

@PostConstruct
public void initModel() {

    model = new DefaultMenuModel();
    viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();

    String viewId = viewRoot.getViewId();

    model.addMenuItem(menuHelper.itemMenuCreator(viewId, null, "Dashboard", "/pages/list.xhtml"));
    model.addMenuItem(menuHelper.itemMenuCreator(viewId, null, "Configuration", "/pages/config.xhtml"));
}

public MenuModel getModel() {
    return model;
}
}
```

Have anybody some ideas how to implement this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an object of a class that implements the ActionListener interface to the menu item by using the method MenuItem.addActionListener(ActionListener) like so:

```
menuItem.addActionListener(actionListener);
```